# Why doesn't my OpenMP simd directive have any use?

Tags: openmp, simd

I have tried these codes to test SIMD directive in OpenMP.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cmath>
#define N 4096
#define M 1000
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    timeval start,end;
    float a[N],b[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        b[i]=i;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
    #pragma omp simd 
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            a[i]=pow(b[i],2.1);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    int time_used=1000000*(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);
    cout<<"time_used="<<time_used<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

But either I compiled it by

```
g++ -fopenmp simd.cpp
```

or

```
g++ simd.cpp
```

their reports for "time_used" are almost the same.It looks like the SIMD directive I used doesn't have any use?
Thanks!

Additional questions:
I replaced

```
a[i]=pow(b[i],2.1);
```

by

```
a[i]=b[i]+2.1;
```

and when I compile them by

```
g++ -fopenmp simd.cpp
```

the output of "time_used" is about 12000.
When I compile them by

```
g++ simd.cpp
```

the output of "time_used" is about 12000,almost the same as before.

My computer: Haswell i5,8g RAM,ubuntu kylin 16.04,gcc 5.4.0

Comment: Function calls are not likely to be vectorized until the functions are explicitly compiled for SIMD calls. And `std::pow` is probably not as its complexity is not at the level of simple additions/multiplications/... Btw: Please provide the measured times as "are almost the same" is very vague.

Comment: As the previous comment hints, you require a simd math library such as the one provided by Intel c++ to get benefit of vectorization in such cases.

Comment: @Shadow I change funcion "pow" to simple addition,but no acceleration as before...

Comment: Do I read your question right ?  You get a time of `12000/1000000==0.12` seconds ?  My guess would be that your compiler is optimising the loop away entirely because its results are not used.  Or maybe my eyes deceive me.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't enable any optimizate settings,and before I replace function pow by simple addition,the time costs is about 250000,which is much more than simple addition.So I think it's not the case that my compiler optimises it...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't auto-vectorize *function calls*. It can only vectorize specific arithmetic operations that can be done using SIMD instructions.

Therefore, you need a vector math library that implements the `pow` function using SIMD instructions. [Intel provides one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl). I'm not sure if `pow` is one of the functions that it offers with vector optimizations, but I imagine it is. You should also beware that Intel's math library may not be optimal on AMD processors.

[You claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430780/why-doesnt-my-openmp-simd-directive-have-any-use#comment75867317_44430780) that you tried changing the `pow` function call to a simple addition, but didn't see any improvement in the results. I'm not quite sure how that is possible, because if you change the inner loop from:

```
a[i]=pow(b[i],2.1);
```

to, say:

```
a[i] += b[i];
```

or:

```
a[i] += (b[i] * 2);
```

then [GCC, with optimizations enabled, notices that you never use the result and *elides the entire thing*](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Csys/time.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccmath%3E%0A%23define+N+4096%0A%23define+M+1000%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++timeval+start,end%3B%0A++++float+a%5BN%5D,b%5BN%5D%3B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3Bi%3CN%3Bi%2B%2B)%0A++++++++b%5Bi%5D%3Di%3B%0A++++gettimeofday(%26start,NULL)%3B%0A++++for(int+j%3D0%3Bj%3CM%3Bj%2B%2B)%0A++++%7B%0A++++%23pragma+omp+simd+%0A++++++++for(int+i%3D0%3Bi%3CN%3Bi%2B%2B)%0A++++++++++++a%5Bi%5D+%2B%3D+(b%5Bi%5D+*+2)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++gettimeofday(%26end,NULL)%3B%0A++++int+time_used%3D1000000*(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)%2B(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)%3B%0A++++cout%3C%3C%22time_used%3D%22%3C%3Ctime_used%3C%3Cendl%3B%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:46.96823110303906,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g71,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-m64+-O3+-fopenmp',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:53.031768896960955,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4). It was unable to perform this optimization with the `pow` function call, because it didn't know whether the function had any other side-effects. However, with code that is visible to the optimizer, it can…well, *optimize* it. In some cases, it might be able to vectorize it. In this case, it was able to remove it entirely.

If you tried code where the optimizer removed this loop entirely, and you still didn't see an improvement on your benchmark scores, then clearly this is not a bottleneck in your code and you needn't worry about trying to vectorize it.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't read assembly language...Is my usage of "#pragma omp simd" right?Thanks!

Comment: That usage of pragma omp simd would be fine for icpc; it would produce a call to the simd short vector library at -O2 and above even if options such as -fp-model source are set.  As mentioned previously, -O0 probably disables pragma omp simd with many compilers.  g++ would normally ignore pragma simd when making a library function call.  As others pointed out, optimizing compilers are free to cut your loop down to 0 or 1 iteration when it is clear there are no side effects.

Comment: @tim18 Intel's compiler doesn't auto-vectorize opaque function calls either, even with `#pragma omp simd`. The difference is, it uses Intel's math library and inlines the `pow` function, which means that it can optimize around it (because it is no longer opaque). And yes, it eliminates the call entirely inside the inner loop in this example, because it detects that it is not used. If you [construct the code so it is used](https://godbolt.org/g/YWHXef), it unrolls the loop and emits calls to an internal library function, `__svml_pow2`, which is an optimized implementation of `pow`.

Comment: @tim18 Must I use "-O2" to enable "#pragma omp simd"?I tried another example program to test it.When I add "-O2" after "g++",I see the hints of acceleration...